# Special emphasis on observation by circling it in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, geometry

I have a dataset with categorical data with 31 levels. I want to show their distribution in a scatterplot with ggplot, but I want to place special emphasis on some of the datapoints, like the red circle over here:

[image]

It is my preference to have a red dotted circle around the observation that is at data point [x = 10, y = 6]. Preferably, the solution is sustainable, but manual circling advice is also welcom :). This is my script

```
library(ggplot2)

#dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
             n = rep(1:31, 1),
             value = c(3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 6, 7, 9, 8, 6, 10, 11, 11, 11, 13, 15, 17, 16, 18, 18, 20, 20, 23, 22, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 29))

#set correct data type
df1$name <- as.factor(df1$name)

#produce color vector
color <- grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)] 
col_sample <- sample(color, 31)
col_sample <- as.vector(col_sample)

#scatterplot
median_scatter <- ggplot(data = df1,
                     aes(x = n, 
                         y = value,
                         colour = name))
median_scatter + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=col_sample)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a subset of your data, i.e. `df1[df1$name == "j", ]` which corresponds to point of interest to plot on another `geom_point`, and pick a shape that is an open circle, and define color, size and stroke to your liking.

```
median_scatter + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=col_sample) +
  geom_point(data=df1[df1$name == "j", ], colour="red", shape=1, size=4, stroke=1.5)
```

Unfortunately no dashed circle shape is available.

[image]

Comment: geom_djork(savior = T)

Comment: Haha good one :)  Btw, to make this comment useful, I suppose there is a way to hack points of a circle and plot it with `geom_line` with `linetype="dashed"`.